# How do I pin Diablo III to my taskbar but not have it show up twice?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I pin *Diablo III* to my taskbar, it will show up twice when the game launches, how do I prevent this?  It's irritating on multiple monitors when trying to switch back and instead accidentally attempting to re-launch it.

> *Diablo III* pinned on taskbar, then after launching:
>
> [image]

Comment: wouldn't this be valid for any game?

Comment: @Foxtrot likely others with launchers

Answer (score 8):

Instead of pinning the *Diablo III* link in the Start Menu which is really the launcher, pin the program itself.  While the game is running, right-click it's icon and select "Pin this program to taskbar"

[image]

You can then unpin the other pinned *Diablo III* link (you may need to un-pin it from within the start menu rather than the taskbar)

[image]

Despite attempting to launch the program directly, the game will still run through the launcher/patcher.

Voila.

[image]